# How do I set links to be opened in a new tab beside the original one in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Whenever there is a clickable link in a page in Chrome I want it to open in a new tab beside it.  How do I do that?  Only clickable links not every thing on a webpage.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried middle clicking? If not Ctrl+click (or command+click in OSX) should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

There are several Chrome extensions that allow you to do this. You can find an overview of them at this link https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/open%20all%20links.